# Authentication and authorization with the seperate database multi-tenat approach

Tags: asp.net-membership, multi-tenant

starting a proof of concept for this model it appears not to be possible to configure the membership provider per request to the respective clients database. It appears that the web application instantiates the membership providers on application start and doesn't allow modification to this during subsequent requests.

I have tried using reflection and modifying the connection string in the Application_BeginRequest (in the global.aspx) but it appears that the membership provider is designed and implemented to only initialise once per application rather than per request.

This implies for the separate database approach,  the default asp.net membership provider wont work with the single application/multiple database  (multitenant seperate database) model.

what authentication/authorization model do people use in this architecture? do they use a custom implementation of the Microsoft membership providers or do they use a different package or library?

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a multi-tenant application development scenario, the best preferred is a SSO or to go with a custom profile management system.

In order for you to enable tenant based authentication using the databases, you can have a connection string manager that identifies your tenant based on some of the criteria like the company code or the URL and then use the user login data from that database for that tenant's users.

The usage will be like you identify / infer the tenant code  from the login credentials and then choose the database that is available for that tenant and then authenticate the user against this database. Hence the tenants can have their own databases for their user's authentication.

This is feasible and can also comply with the regulatory requirements that may be for different tenants based on their geography.